# How replace returned observable with a new one RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, rx-java2

I have one case when I need to return an `observable` immediately, but then replace this observable with another one.

Here is an example

```
    private Flowable<byte[]> mFlowableStream = Flowable.empty();

   @Override
    public Flowable<byte[]> startStreamRead() {
        bindToService();
        return mFlowableStream;
    }
```

And then after binding to service I provide it a callback connection like that

```
@Override
public void bindToService() {
    mAppContext.bindService(new Intent(mAppContext,StreamService.class), mServiceConnection, 0);
}

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {

       mServiceInterection = ((StreamServiceInterection.LocalBinder) binder).getServiceInteractor();
        mStreamDisposable = mServiceInterection.getStream()
                .subscribe(new Consumer<byte[]>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(byte[] data) throws Exception {

                    }
                });
    }
```

What I want to do is to somehow replace returned previously `mFlowableStream` with a new observable that I got from service.

What are possible strategies to implement this ? Maybe I should return some other value, like `Future`.

Please suggest how to solve this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Flowable.create** instead of **Flowable.empty**

Then when new data come, just push to flowable.
Like Example

```
final ArrayList<FlowableEmitter<Integer>> arrEmitter = new ArrayList<>();

    Flowable<Integer> futureFlow = Flowable.create(new FlowableOnSubscribe<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(final FlowableEmitter<Integer> e) throws Exception {
            e.onNext(1);
            e.onNext(2);

            arrEmitter.add(e); // hold emitter to use later
        }
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);

    futureFlow.subscribe(new ResourceSubscriber<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer integer) {
            System.out.println("onNext: " + integer);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            System.out.println("onComplete");
        }
    });


    // =========== When data come 
    FlowableEmitter<Integer> holdEmitter = arrEmitter.get(0);

    holdEmitter.onNext(3);
```

Or use you can use **Subject* type according to your need

[Understanding RxJava Subject — Publish, Replay, Behavior and Async Subject](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-rxjava-subject-publish-replay-behavior-and-async-subject-224d663d452f)